# What is the insecure orange tag in the modules release pages?

Tags: community-official-site

I was checking today the [release page](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar/releases) for the Admin Toolbar module and see an orange tag with the text **Insecure** I tried to find an explanation about it without luck, anyone knows what this means?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a tag that is automatically added when a more recent release for the same branch has been tagged as release that fixes security issues. In the case of the 3.0.1 release, it's the [3.0.2 release](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar/releases/3.0.2).

> [image: screenshot]

The *Security update* tag is manually added from the Security Team, and it cannot be removed once added. (Actually, the release type cannot be anymore changed, once *Security update* is selected.)

> [image: screenshot]